# jQuery toggle issue with closing other open items

Tags: jquery, if-statement, logic

I have a situation where I have several toggle-able items on a page.  When toggling open one item, it should search for items that are already toggled open and close them before opening the new item.

There should only ever be one item toggled open at a time.

Here is my most basic code attempt at this:

```
$('.board-of-directors .expand').click(function(event) {        
    $(this).toggleClass('contract');
    $(this).parent().find('.popout').toggle();
});
```

This iteration of the code does not close previously opened items, so I updated it to this:

```
$('.board-of-directors .expand').click(function(event) {    
    $('.contract').parent().find('.popout').toggle(); /* closes any previously opened items */
    $('.contract').removeClass('contract'); /* removes the class which shows items as open */
    $(this).toggleClass('contract');
    $(this).parent().find('.popout').toggle();
});
```

This worked to a point. It closes other open items.  The issue is that when you open an item, and then click on the same item to manually close it, nothing "appears" to happen. In actuality, it closes and re-opens the same item, following the code above.

I have tried numerous approaches to accomplish this, including adding/remove classes, simulating click events on open items to close them, etc, but the end result is always the same.

I also tried adding a more complicated if/else statement, but it failed to work around this issue.  I guess its less of a jQuery issue and more of a logic issue.

Here was the "if" attempt:

```
$('.board-of-directors .expand').click(function(event) {        
    if($('.board-of-directors div').hasClass('contract')) {
        $('.member div').removeClass("contract");
        $('.member div:first-child').addClass("expand");
        $('.right div').removeClass("director-selected");
        $(".popout").fadeOut('fast');       
    };
    if($(this).hasClass('contract')) {
        $(this).removeClass("contract");
        $(this).addClass("expand");
        $(this).parent().removeClass("director-selected");
        $(this).stop().parent().find(".popout").fadeOut('fast');        
    };
    if($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
        $(this).addClass("contract");
        $(this).removeClass("expand");
        $(this).parent().addClass("director-selected");
        $(this).stop().parent().find(".popout").fadeIn('fast');     
    };
});
```

Can someone please help me to accomplish what I want?

When an item is toggled open, it should close all other items. At the same time, when clicking to close the item you just opened, it should close without re-opening.

EDIT: Editing to add an example of the HTML. This is in a WordPress query.

```
<div class="board-of-directors">
     <div class="member">
          <div class="expand"></div>
          <div class="name">
               <?php the_title();?>
          </div>
          <div class="position"><?php echo $position;?></div>
          <div class="popout">
               <?php echo $bio;?>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/G65J7/5/. Since you did not provide any DOM, I made a general setup.

The HTML part:

```
<h1>Board of directors</h1>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item is-active">
    <h2>Jon Doe</h2>
    <a href="#" class="list__toggle">show more</a>
    <div class="list__item--more-info">
      wow, this is great
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <h2>Jane Doe</h2>
    <a href="#" class="list__toggle">show more</a>
    <div class="list__item--more-info">
      wow, this is great
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Very little CSS; as you can see the class **is-active** is responsible for displaying.

```
.list__item--more-info {
    display: none;
}
.is-active .list__item--more-info {
    display: block;
}
```

And some jQuery: onClick is first closes all active items and then applies -based on the state of the current toggle- the class to display.

```
$('.list__toggle').on('click', function (event) {
    var $this = $(event.currentTarget);
    var $parent = $this.closest('.list__item');
    var $openedItems = $('.list__item.is-active');
    var isCurrentlyActive = $parent.hasClass('is-active');

    $openedItems.removeClass('is-active');
    $parent.toggleClass('is-active', !isCurrentlyActive);

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't close other items when clicking to open another. It merely prevents you from opening another when one is already opened.

Comment: Sorry @ZachNicodemous; did not test properly. Am fixing things now.

Comment: Javascript is fixed now (and more efficient :P).

Comment: It was a mis-click, sorry. Just in the process of testing this on my project. Will accept if it works :)

Comment: Am having trouble applying this to my HTML, but I'm sure I'll figure it out shortly.

Comment: A lot of it can stay the same, but you need a few changes:  
(1) apply the click handler to `$('.expand')`  
(2) change the value of $parent: to `$this.closest('.member')`  
(3) the same goes for $openedItems: `$('.member.is-active')`  
(4) add `is-active` (or another class name) to `.member'`
(5) apply CSS to `.member.is-active'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way to do this would be to only add the same class, no matter which element it is.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kydQ6/) Example

HTML:

```
<div class="abc"></div>

<div class="def"></div>

<div class="ghi"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; margin: 20px; }

.abc.z { background: red; }

.def.z { width: 300px; }

.ghi.z { box-shadow: 0 0 8px black; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $('div').removeClass('z');
    $(this).addClass('z');
});
```

---

So instead of having an add/remove class of `contract` , `expand`, `director-selected`, etc..you remove the class of `z` to all of them, and then give the class of `z` to the one you clicked on.  Also, the 'div' is just an example, you should  make a class that all these items share in place of just `div`.

Please note to make sure to do `.abc.z` , and not `.abc .z` There's a big difference.

---

**EDIT:**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kydQ6/1/)

```
$('div').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('z')) {
        $('div').removeClass('z');
    }
        else {
            $('div').removeClass('z');
            $(this).addClass('z');
        }
});
```

Ok, this works both ways now. For when you click on the same div twice then it will close that div , as well as all the others.

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your approach: when `z` is your active state class and you have toggled item with class `abc`. If you want to close this item it first removes all `z` classes and then adds it. Leads to the same issue @Zach is talking about.